# Table view scrolling is erratic and jumpy even though I reuse cells?

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, scroll, tableview

Okay, so I'm not sure whats been happening with my Table view, but it seems to act a bit strange now that I load images from parse onto it. At first, it ran smoothly, but now that I'm working in ios 9, the scrolling is horrible

Optimizations I've used to reduce this(Keep in mind they do not really help.)
-Removed transparent objects and set them to default background
-reused table cells 
-Tried to use lower quality images

Here is my code

```
import UIKit

class mainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

    var deleteArray = [String]()
    var followArray = [String]()

    var resultsLocationArray = [String]()
    var datetextfielArray = [String]()

    var imageDates = [String]()

    var resultsNameArray = [String]()
    var resulltsImageFiles = [PFFile]()
    var resultsTweetArray = [String]()

    var resultsHasImageArray = [String]()
    var resultsTweetImageFiles = [PFFile?]()

    var refresher:UIRefreshControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

            // Uncomment to change the width of menu
            //self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
        }


        let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
        let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

        resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theHeight)

        let tweetBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Compose, target: self, action: Selector("tweetBtn_click"))

        let searchBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Search, target: self, action: Selector("searchBtn_click"))

        let buttonArray = NSArray(objects: tweetBtn, searchBtn)
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttonArray as? [UIBarButtonItem]

        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.resultsTable.addSubview(refresher)


    }

    func refresh() {

        print("refresh table")

        refreshResults()

    }

    func refreshResults() {

        followArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resulltsImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsTweetArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsLocationArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsHasImageArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        resultsTweetImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        datetextfielArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "follow")
        followQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        followQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

        let objects = followQuery.findObjects()

        for object in objects! {

            self.followArray.append(object.objectForKey("userToFollow") as! String)


        }



        let query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "tweets")




        query.whereKey("userName", containedIn: followArray)
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in



            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {


                    self.resultsNameArray.append(object.objectForKey("profileName") as! String)
                    self.resulltsImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("photo") as! PFFile)
                    self.resultsTweetArray.append(object.objectForKey("tweet") as! String)
                    //resultsLocationArray

                     self.resultsLocationArray.append(object.objectForKey("tweetlocation") as! String)
                    self.resultsHasImageArray.append(object.objectForKey("hasImage") as! String)
                    self.resultsTweetImageFiles.append(object.objectForKey("tweetImage") as? PFFile)
                    self.datetextfielArray.append(object.objectForKey("datetextfield") as! String)

                    self.resultsTable.reloadData()

                }

                self.refresher.endRefreshing()

            }
        }

    }







    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false


        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        nav?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]



        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    }
     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        refreshResults()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return resultsNameArray.count


    }





    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {




        if resultsHasImageArray[indexPath.row] == "yes" {

            return self.view.frame.size.width + 130


        } else {


            return 130

        }

    }
    //var theDtS = dtFormater.stringFromDate(self.dateArray[i])







    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



          let cell:mainCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! mainCell



        cell.tweetImg.hidden = true

        cell.locationTxt.text = self.resultsLocationArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.profileLbl.text = self.resultsNameArray[indexPath.row]
         cell.messageTxt.text = self.resultsTweetArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.datetextfield.text = self.datetextfielArray[indexPath.row]


        resulltsImageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            //resultsLocationArray

            if error == nil {

                let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                cell.imgView.image = image

            }

        }


        if resultsHasImageArray[indexPath.row] == "yes" {

            let theWidth = view.frame.size.width

           cell.tweetImg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, theWidth, theWidth)
            cell.tweetImg.hidden = false

            resultsTweetImageFiles[indexPath.row]?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (imageData:NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    cell.tweetImg.image = image

                }

            })

        }

        return cell

    }

    func tweetBtn_click() {

        print("tweet pressed")

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoTweetVCFromMainVC", sender: self)

    }

    func searchBtn_click() {

     print("search pressed")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gotoUsersVCFromMainVC", sender: self)

    }





}
```

Comment: Please narrow down your code to just the relevant parts.

Comment: Use Instruments to see where your code is having issues.

Comment: I tried using instruments, however it just shows me a bunch of random files that i did not code, most likely part of Xcode's build system.

Comment: You need to learn how to use Instruments (And specifically the performance instrument.) You want to prune the call tree to hide system calls.